# Estructura de control en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nueva en programacion web y tengo un archivo .html donde quiero utilizar javascrip con la estructura de control `if else` y otras estructuras como `while`, `switch`, `do while`, `do` y `for`  pero hasta el momento tengo esto pero no se como hacer la estructura para que me funcione, alguien me podría ayudar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function var() {

 if( numero >= 100 )
{
    alert("Mayor o igual de 100");
}
 else(numero<=50)
{
    alert("Menor de 100");
}
}   
</script>
<body>
<form action="#" name="numero">
     <input type="text" name="numero"> Escibe un número <br/><br/>
 <input type="button" onclick="var()" value="Pulsar" />
 </form>
   <p id="respuesta"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes usar la palabre clave `var` como nombre de funcion. Puedes usar alguna otra palabra para que funcione.

Revisa otras palabras reservadas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc() {
 var numero=document.forms['numero'].numero.value;
 if( numero >= 100 )
 {
    alert("Mayor o igual de 100");
 }
 else // if(numero<=50) 
 {
    alert("Menor de 100");
 }
}   
</script>
<body>
<form action="#" name="numero">
     <input type="text" name="numero"> Escibe un número <br/><br/>
 <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Pulsar" />
 </form>
   <p id="respuesta"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Por otro lado, la variable `numero` no se carga automaticamente del formulario, se debe obtener del control como en el ejemplo:

```
var numero=document.forms['numero'].numero.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Siendo que estás empezando en programación web, aparte sobre lo que ya te ha señalado @F.Igor sobre el uso de una palabra reservada (`var`) para nombrar una función, me permito advertirte sobre algunas malas prácticas en tu código.

En Javascript hay un paradigma conocido como [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), el cual recomienda, entre otras cosas, que haya separación de responsabilidades en el código, de modo que el código del DOM (HTML) no sea dependiente del código Javascript. Según ese paradigma, el uso de funciones in line es una mala práctica. Por funciones in line se entiende aquellas funciones que colocas dentro de los elementos HTML, como ocurre con `onclick="var()"` aquí: `<input type="button" onclick="var()" value="Pulsar" />`

¿Qué problemas trae esto? Imaginemos un programa con cientos o miles de archivos html donde has puesto varios miles de funciones in line como esta. Y al cabo de un año el programa evoluciona y te dicen que ahora la función tal que pusiste in line en 12,546 archivos tiene que cambiar, que ahora esa función va a recibir un parámetro nuevo, etc. Pues eso, a rebuscar, a ver, a adivinar, donde rayos pusiste esa función 12,546 veces para modificar la función y el archivo javascript **que debiste poner in situ en ese contexto**.

Pero, si haces caso a uno de los principios de *Unobtrusive JavaScript*, tu código será independiente del DOM. Para lograr eso, eh Javascript existe lo que se conocen como *listeners* o escuchadores de eventos. En este caso, puedes asignar un *listener*, el cual escuchará el evento `onclick` del botón. Es lo mismo que haría el `onclick` que tienes in line, sólo que aquí el código es independiente. Y además tienes la ventaja de reutilizar código. Imaginemos que necesitas usar esta función en 12,546 archivos o contextos. Pues simplemente vas a incluir un solo archivo en esos contextos y cualquier cambio se hará en ese sólo archivo.

Este es un ejemplo funcional de tu código, aplicando ese principio. Te aconsejo que lo tengas en cuenta para tus programas. El código quedará más limpio y será más fácil de mantener. Para hacer la escucha, ha dado un `id` al botón que envía los datos.

```js
var btnSend = document.getElementById('btnSend');
btnSend.onclick = function() {
  /*Aquí se obtiene el valor del 1er input que haya en el DOM*/
  var mNumber = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  /*Para mostrar la respuesta*/
  var mText = document.getElementById("respuesta");
  if (mNumber >= 100) {
    var mStatus = "Mayor o igual de 100";
    /*En este caso no haría falta comparar más*/
  } else {
    var mStatus = "Menor de 100";
  }
  alert(mStatus);
  mText.textContent = mStatus;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" name="numero"> Escibe un número <br/><br/>
  <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Pulsar" />
</form>
<p id="respuesta"></p>
```